# Maven/Java Fetching Constants from an optional module

Tags: java, maven

This is going to be a bit more theoretical than practical, but here goes: I have a swing application that uses maven. It displays various panels (screens) depending on what module I load via a maven profile.

Think of it as a main swing program that, depending on which maven profile is built, it includes a dependency to a second module, be it either ModuleA or ModuleB.

For easier context, imagine the main swing program to be a header, a sidebar, and a footer with an empty center panel. The center panel is filled with 'screens' from the secondary module and change which screens are shown depending on which module is built in via the profile.

The main swing program has a title label for the screen in the header, but the home screen title label is different depending on which secondary module is loaded. If I had a constants file in each secondary module that contained the text, how would I access that modularly without tying the main program to either one of the modules?

Answer (score 1):

Use inheritance. Make ModuleA and ModuleB share same ancestor.

```
public abstract class AbstractModule{
    public abstract String getTitle();
}

public class ModuleA extends AbstractModule{
    @Override
    public String getTitle(){
        return "I am module A";
    }
}
```

And in the main program use AbstractModule which can be either ModuleA or ModuleB.

Comment: I was considering this, but how would one access it from the main program? Since the main program would house the abstract class while ModuleA/ModuleB would contain the extensions. Would the main class be able to call new AbstractModule.getTitle() and get the correct data? I ask because the main program wouldn't be able to reference "new ModuleA" without a dependency tying it to ModuleA.

Comment: No, you cannot instantiate abstract class. I thought you have solved the issue of creating different instances if you are just interested in title. How does it work for you now? You have two implementations in different modules with same package and class name?

Comment: Right now, we have a class GenericConstants in the main class and each module has a ModuleAConstants extends GenericConstants. The titles are currently stored in the GenericConstants class directly and accessed from there. I want to move them in the specific modules as they are unrelated to the main class. Also we have a terrible architecture that builds a map based on hard coded class names to locate the individual screens in the modules from the main module. Looking to improve.

Comment: I may take your idea there and create a HomeScreen class with the same package in each moduleA and moduleB. I'll put those constants in that class. Should be referencable by using the hard-coded "package.classname". Thank you! If you include that info in the main answer, I will accept it.